# Core Web API returns error in XML instead of JSON

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm playing with .NET6 and Core Web API.
I want to process and return two data formats - JSON and XML.
These formats should be strictly separated.

I have added XML formatters and JSON from Newtonsoft, and created two separate methods in the controller.
When I post an incorrect JSON to "api/json" it throws an error, but the problem is that the error is in XML, not in JSON.

Can anyone help what should be done to make it return the formats I need?

**Program.cs**

```cs
builder.Services.AddControllers()
.AddXmlSerializerFormatters()
.AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

**MyApiController.cs**

```cs
[Route("api/json")]
[Consumes("application/json")]
[Produces("application/json")]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult JsonPost([FromBody] JObject jsonRequest)
{
   return Ok(jsonRequest);
}

...

[Route("api/xml")]
[Consumes("application/xml")]
[Produces("application/xml")]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult XmlPost([FromBody] XDocument xmlRequest)
{
   return Ok(xmlRequest);
}
```

**EDIT**

[request headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEXNg.png)

[request and response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MSG6.png)

When I remove

```cs
.AddXmlSerializerFormatters()
```

then I get the JSON error response, but XML doesn't work.

I need to set somehow that JsonPost() always returns JSON, even there is an unhandled exception, and XmlPost() always returns XML.

Comment: You need content negotiation. What headers do you pass?

Comment: Not sure what headers you mean, but I've updated the topic.

Comment: Accept: application/json

Comment: Ok, I added "Accept" in Postman and it worked. However, can this be forced in code?